# Best practice to send only required fields in REST API in Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, sylius

We need to send certificates list to another application using REST API. So Object response contains

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "orderId":123,
      "certificateStatus":true,
      "certificateNo":"xyz123abc",
      "customer":{
         "id":36,
         "email":"abc@cc.com",
         "firstName":"abc",
         "lastName":"dfg",
         "user":{
            "id":23,
            "username":"abc@cc.com",
            "enabled":true,
            "kycStatus":false
         },
         "_links":{
            "self":{
               "href":"\/app_dev.php\/api\/v1\/customers\/36"
            }
         }
      },
      "orderItem":{
         "id":60,
         "quantity":2,
         "unitPrice":177581,
         "total":355162,
         "units":[
            {
               "id":1711,
               "adjustments":[

               ],
               "adjustmentsTotal":0
            },
            {
               "id":1712,
               "adjustments":[

               ],
               "adjustmentsTotal":0
            }
         ],
         "unitsTotal":355162,
         "adjustments":[

         ],
         "adjustmentsTotal":0,
         "variant":{
            "id":334,
            "code":"pool-gold-1oz",
            "optionValues":[

            ],
            "position":0,
            "translations":{
               "en_US":{
                  "locale":"en_US",
                  "id":334
               }
            },
            "version":2,
            "tracked":false,
            "channelPricings":{
               "UK_WEB":{
                  "channelCode":"UK_WEB",
                  "price":177582
               },
               "US_WEB":{
                  "channelCode":"US_WEB",
                  "price":177581
               }
            },
            "_links":{
               "self":{
                  "href":"\/app_dev.php\/api\/v1\/products\/pool-gold-1oz\/variants\/pool-gold-1oz"
               }
            }
         },
         "_links":{
            "order":{
               "href":"\/app_dev.php\/api\/v1\/orders\/29"
            },
            "product":{
               "href":"\/app_dev.php\/api\/v1\/products\/pool-gold-1oz"
            },
            "variant":{
               "href":"\/app_dev.php\/api\/v1\/products\/pool-gold-1oz\/variants\/pool-gold-1oz"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I want JSON response something like below sample response
 - which need extra custom fields 
 - status code and message
 - extra fields
 - remove unwanted fields

```
    {
   "code":"custom_code_xxx",
   "message":"Successful",
   "data":[
      {
         "custom_extra_fields1":"asd",
         "custom_extra_fields2":"xyz",
         "id":1,
         "orderId":123,
         "certificateStatus":true,
         "certificateNo":"xyz123abc",
         "customer":{
            "id":36,
            "email":"abc@xyz.com",
            "firstName":"abc",
            "lastName":"dfg",
            "user":{
               "id":23,
               "username":"abc@xyz.com",
               "enabled":true,
               "kycStatus":false
            }
         },
         "orderItem":{
            "id":60,
            "quantity":2,
            "unitPrice":177581,
            "total":355162,
            "unitsTotal":355162
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Any best practice we can use to simplify JSON response ? or we need to construct an array in the required format

Answer (score 0):

When you use something like e.g. [**JMS Serializer Bundle**](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/#JMSSerializerBundle) you can use

[Virtual Properties](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) for additional custom fields.

And [Groups](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#groups) and/or [Exclusion Policies](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#exclude) to get rid of unwanted fields.

When using the [**Symfony Serializer**](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html) you have at least the option of [Groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations) to exclude some fields.

To add additional fields I'd either use simply an additional Getter in your Entity (no clean approach but helps) or work with custom normalizers and/or encoders.

Comment: According to my understanding expose will be applicable to a complete model. But  in my case, I need to hide some fields in one api that might require to expose in another API

Comment: @stefun - so did you check my other option: Groups? it's available for both common serializers - which one do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Stefun,

You should create a new data transfer object containing the properties that you want as response. Then return that object as a json.

You then create an assembler class that builds your DTO based on the original object.